# How can I view n_lru_nuked in varnish 3.0.5?

Tags: varnish

I'm trying to monitor varnish cache evictions and can't seem to find out how to view the `n_lru_nuked` counter on varnish 3.0.5. `varnishstat` isn't finding the counter:

```
$ varnishstat -f n_lru_moved,n_lru_nuked

0+21:44:54
Hitrate ratio:        1        1        1
Hitrate avg:     0.8292   0.8292   0.8292

       31943          .            .   n_lru_moved - N LRU moved objects
```

Is the method for monitoring cache evictions different in 3.0.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one else has offered anything up here. I thought I would let you know you're not alone trying to find the answer.

I have the same question and I'm starting to think varnishstat perhaps doesn't report metrics with entirely null values.

I have a test-bed server that I might deliberately starve of cache storage and see what happens.  If I can confirm this behaviour, I will report back.

Perhaps someone might offer their expertise?

**Update**
OK I can confirm that varnishstat appears to save terminal space by *not* reporting counters that are entirely 0 or null.

This is because of the continuously updated display mode.

If you run varnishstat non-interactive / continuous then the stat does indeed show.

```
[root@test nginx]# varnishstat -1 -f n_lru_nuked,n_expired,n_sess,n_sess_mem
n_sess_mem                  20          .   N struct sess_mem
n_sess                       0          .   N struct sess
n_expired                   57          .   N expired objects
n_lru_nuked                  0          .   N LRU nuked objects
[root@test nginx]#
```

Comment: varnish 4 and ubuntu 16.04, you may need to add MAIN like as these:
varnishstat -1 -f MAIN.n_lru_nuked